# Product & Feature Comparison of EJBCA, Active Directory Certificate Services, or Entrust Authority Security Manager?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

I'm currently beginning analysis in this field and stumbled across the thread titled: "[Comparison and difference between CAs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126629/comparison-and-difference-between-cas/126810?newreg=0c63b9a0278c4423b590cb914b309400)"

The question seems largely unresolved. Does there exist any product or feature comparison list across these 3 products and any others? I.e. what are the guiding decisions/features someone would assess when choosing across these three products (and please mention any others that may not be on the list)?

1. EJBCA
2. Active Directory Certificate Services
3. Entrust Authority Security Manager